# 301 redirect www.example.com/a-site.com to www.example.com/a-site-com for a bunch

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm having trouble redirecting URLs with a domain extension in them.

For instance I have the following URLs:

- `www.example.com/another-site.nl`
- `www.example.com/yet-another-site.com`

I want a redirect from every dot after the slash to a stripe. So they must become:

- `www.example.com/another-site-nl`
- `www.example.com/yet-another-site-com`

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: I tried some examples in htacces but I'm not getting close. The following extensions occur: .nl, .com, .be and .de

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to redirect urls with one 'path segment' ending with .nl, .com, .be or .de. With mod_rewrite you can do this using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.(nl|com|be|de)$ $1-$2 [R,L]
```

After testing that this works correctly, replace the `R` flag with `R=301`.

Comment: Almost there! My question should have been a bit differerent. There is a folder in between so the url is www.site.com/folder/another-site.nl sorry!

Comment: Does anyone know this little change?

Comment: Please read through [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mod-rewrite), [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and teach yourself how to write a regex. Use the documentation of PREG-regexes to find out what the regex in this rewriterule means. You then should have no problem adding your folder. I am not going to spoon-feed you.